# Apache Cassandra logging in WARN doesn't have much info

Tags: cassandra

Recently switching from Datastax to apache Cassandra. We have setting for Cassandra logging to warn not much information is written in apache cassandra system.log . Can some one let me know what would be the best setting to display logs in apache cassandra.

I know debug helps but we don't want dbs logging continuously in debug mode

this is our current setting

```
 <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="SYSTEMLOG" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCDEBUGLOG" /> <!-- Comment this line to disable debug.log -->
    <!--
    <appender-ref ref="LogbackMetrics" />
    -->
  </root>
  <logger name="org.apache.cassandra" level="WARN"/>
  <logger name="com.thinkaurelius.thrift" level="ERROR"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case we keep the level at INFO in prod, and never DEBUG unless we are debugging something.
So i think you can try it with below change

```
<!--<appender-ref ref="ASYNCDEBUGLOG" /> -->
<logger name="org.apache.cassandra" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Please note that with this case we won't be having the debug.log info hence if something goes wrong in prod then and it is difficult to reproduce then you wont have that verbosity in system.log as we have in debug.log.

Hence my personal recommendation would be to keep it default (uncomment above) in case 
1. you are ok with minimal performance impact,
2. don't have space issue, 
3. not using 2.2 version (as it has performance [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14318) with debug enabled). and 4. don't have infra environment where you can reproduce prod issue later.
If you are uncomfortable with any above described point then keep it at info level and enable debug only at time of troubleshooting.

For more details: check [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10241), [this](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/LoggingGuidelines) and [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14326)